# How do I find all the houses in Auburn Pines?

Tags: costume-quest

I've trick-or-treated 18/20 houses in Auburn Pines, but I cannot for the life of me seem to find the other two. (This is in the PC version of Costume Quest.)

I know the game has no map in it, but does anyone know of a map someone's made with the houses' locations?

Alternatively, is there some task I haven't yet completed that would give me access to the houses I haven't found? Or are some of the houses in a non-obvious place (not reachable from the road, for example)?

Here are the quests I've completed so far:

- Robot Repair
- Programmed for Protection
- Pie for the Putterpam
- The Patriot's Party
- Auburn Pines Hide 'n' Seek
- This Card is so Rare
- 2/3 Bobbing For Apples Tiers

I have all three Costume Patterns available in Auburn Pines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember, there are no houses off-road! The only tasks that can give you access to houses are the ones you have to complete for a character that doesn't allow you to pass until you finish his request.

To be sure you haven't missed any houses, check if the lights are on. If they are, you haven't knock at that door. On the other hand, lights off means you have already knocked at this house.

Completing the Bobbing for Apples quest will only give you the Sweet Tooth Creepy Treat Card.

Here they are:

> - 2 on your left of your house on the same street.
>
>  - If you take the street that goes to the park (right street from your house), there's 4 houses (2 on the left of the street, 2 on the right)
>
>  - If you take the street that goes to the graveyard (left street from your house), there's 4 houses (2 on the left of the street, 2 on the right)
>
>  - On the horizontal street at the bottom of the park, there's 5 houses (left side of the park: 2 at the top of the street; right side of the park: 1 at the top of the street and 2 at the bottom)
>
>  - On the horizontal street at the top of the park, there's 5 houses (1 at the bottom on the left extremity, 3 at the top of the street and the last at the right extremity).

Comment: Spoiler tag does not work :( Sorry! Can someone edit my post correctly?

Comment: Really weird. SE here does not like sequential spoilers. I added some escaped spaces (&#20;) to make it work.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! The spoiler work so ... that's the important for me ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the houses on the right from your third spoiler tag, I'm still not sure how I missed them.

Comment: I was missing the same two houses! sneaky little things